# Solving a set of equations with absolute values

Tags: linear-algebra, absolute-value

How would you go about solving equations with absolute values? ~

$$
|x − 1| + |y − 5| = 1
$$
$$
|x − 1| − y = −5
$$

Comment: Please show something that you've tried.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-ask-a-good-question for information on how to attract quality answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from the second equation we get $$y+|y-5|=6$$ 
if $$y\geq 5$$ we have $$2y-5=0$$ thus $$y=\frac{11}{2}$$
if $$y<5$$ we have $$y-y+5=6$$ there is no solution in this case.
computing $x$ we get the following solution set
$$x=\frac{3}{2},y=\frac{11}{2}$$
or
$$x=\frac{1}{2},y=\frac{11}{2}$$

Comment: You wrote "from the second equation we get
$y+|y−5|=6$", if you used only the second eq, where did the $x$ go? Am I missing something?

Comment: i solved for $|x-1|=-5+y$ and plug this in the first equation,ok?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Apply this rule: Suppose $f(x)=|x-k|$, then $f(x)$ can be decomposed into:
$$
f(x)=
 \begin{cases}
  x-k, & \text{when } x>k;\\
  0, & \text{when }x=k;\\
  -(x-k), & \text{when }x<k.
 \end{cases}
$$

Comment: Yes, I understand this principle, but for example in the first equation there are two parts with absolute value, that would give me 4 combinations with this method, plus adding in the second equation.. I was hoping there is some simpler way to solve them.

Comment: yes in total, you have to consider four cases: $(x>1,y>5)$,$\ (x>1,y<5)$,$\ (x<1,y>5)$,$\ (x<1,y<5)$. I don't think there is simpler way to solve them, you've to check it manually.